# How to get Jenkins username and password property

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job where I login to a website. The username and password for the website is the same username and password I use for Jenkins.
I want to get the Jenkins username and password and and pass it to the java code i have written to login to the website.

How do I get the Jenkins Username and Password properties?

Background:
Lets say I use "username1" and "password1" to login to Jenkins. I have a website that uses this same login credentials. I have a jenkins job created to login to this website. This jenkins job is used by a lot of people. I want to write the Java code in such a way that when each person login to the system and run this jenkin job, it will get the username and password that this person logged into jenkins and use that username and password to login to the website.
So no one will be able to get the password of others. They will be using their own username and password.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get Jenkins system useres password? The Jenkins user is a system user, that may not even have a password. If it has, as with any users password: you shouldn't be able to get a hold on it(would be a severy security problem if one was able to get the passwords of other users). If i missunderstood I apologize and ask you to clarify your question.

Comment: Simply you create a property in java and take those username and password pass them over from your script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kai, Let me further describe my question. I use "username1" and "password1" to login to Jenkins. I have a website that uses this same login credentials. I have a jenkins job created to login to this website. This jenkins job is used by a lot of people. I want to write the Java code in such a way that when each person login to the system and run this jenkin job, it will get the username and password that this person logged into jenkins and use that username and password to login to the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no generic solution for this.

- How users authenticate towards Jenkins is configured in the "Global Security->Security Realm" section.
- If you configure, for example, LDAP-based authentication, then Jenkins will not store the entered credentials at all (for good reason).
- Therefore, you will not be able to re-use user credentials for authentication towards other services.

Only in the very special case where you select "Jenkins’ own user database" as Security Realm, you might be able to retrieve the password. However, local Jenkins credentials will conflict with your very idea sharing credentials with other services...

Possibly, delegating Jenkins authentication to a servlet container can help -- if you manage to connect the servlet container's authentication machinery to the services that you need to use.